# Why was there a change of specific behaviour for JAXB 2.0 default validation?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb

Can anybody of the Java EE crowd tell me, what were the reasons in those days to make the validation more lenient and don't fail on erroneous XMLs?

Found a description in the docs, but no background information...

> Since unmarshalling invalid XML content is defined in JAXB 2.0, the Unmarshaller default validation event handler was made more lenient than in JAXB 1.0. When schema-derived code generated by JAXB 1.0 binding compiler is registered with JAXBContext, the default unmarshal validation handler is DefaultValidationEventHandler and it terminates the marshal operation after encountering either a fatal error or an error. For a JAXB 2.0 client application, there is no explicitly defined default validation handler and the default event handling only terminates the unmarshal operation after encountering a fatal error.  [from: Interface Unmarshaller](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html)

**EDIT:**
I'll provide an example..

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = getJaxbContext(packages).createUnmarshaller();
// sets event handler to DefaultValidationEventHandler  
// (error and fatal error lead to an exception)
// **DefaultValidationEventHandler is not default by default anymore**
unmarshaller.setEventHandler(null);
Object o = unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

This is the rt (1.7.0_60) implementation of the Setter called:

```
/**
 * Allow an application to register a validation event handler.
 * <p>
 * The validation event handler will be called by the JAXB Provider if any
 * validation errors are encountered during calls to any of the
 * <tt>unmarshal</tt> methods.  If the client application does not register
 * a validation event handler before invoking the unmarshal methods, then
 * all validation events will be silently ignored and may result in
 * unexpected behaviour.
 *
 * @param handler the validation event handler
 * @throws JAXBException if an error was encountered while setting the
 *        event handler
 */
public void setEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler handler)
    throws JAXBException {

    if( handler == null ) {
        eventHandler = new DefaultValidationEventHandler();
    } else {
        eventHandler = handler;
    }
}
```

Why have they changed their mind?

Comment: what is not clear in that documentation? they changed the validation to be optional and defined support for invalid xml. in addition, custom validation is possible by passing own validators, instead of just having to use jaxp.

Comment: this question is not about the way it works.. it's about why things have changed..

Comment: a funny / sad part of the described change is that authors document this change in the javadoc of the Unmarshaller _interface_, yet they somehow forgot to also change the javadoc of the [setEventHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#setEventHandler-javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler-) _interface method_...